# SQL Document Database on Webserver - User Friendly

Tags: sql, database, webserver, document

I'm looking at doing a bit of work for a local charity whose administration rotates every year or so. They want a document database for a large archive of paper documents, but they don't want to deal with buying a server and maintaining it.

Their webpage host allows MySQL databases, lots of bandwidth, and a ton of space. I was thinking that to avoid heavy maintenance/hardware costs, they could run it on there. This wouldn't be high traffic - at most a few users would be using it at a time. Not a public-facing site.

I'd want a fairly simple web-based interface with SQL (probably using PHP, could write it myself if there are no good recommendations) that allows users to add a new entry containing the document name, author, date, physical location, etc. as well as a PDF of the document itself. Then just a simple search function to look through the database for documents.

Has anybody encountered a project like this before or have any advice regarding it? Is there any pre-existing software that can interface with SQL in a simple way like this?

Comment: Could you please clarify something - do you want to store the document in the database itself or just a pointer to the actual file? How complex does your search function need to be? I assume you'll want to search the content of the PDF documents.

Comment: They apparently have an OCR system already in place to scan the documents into PDF. A pointer to the document on the webserver would be fine - would also allow them to browse through the PDFs independently if they wanted to. As for searching, a search inside the PDFs would be nice but not a total necessity. Being able to search the entered data like title, date, author, tags, etc. would be adequate.